# Cleaning up after a dynamically assigned, multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

So, I have dynamically assigned memory to a 2D array:

```
int **paMatrix = new int*[r];

for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
    paMatrix[i] = new int[c];
```

Assume that my code has already defined `r` and `c`. Now I want to free the memory again. If `paMatrix` was single-indexed, the `delete[] paMatrix;` would be enough. Is it also enough in this case, or do I have to write

```
for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
    delete[] paMatrix[i];

delete[] paMatrix;
```

In case I need to call `delete` once for each `new` statement, is there a way to rewrite my code so that I only need a single `delete` statement?

Comment: you have to delete all members. Also, you don't have a 2D array, you have a pointer to pointers (and that's exactly why one delete is not enough).

Comment: you got too many stars to call it a c++ example

Comment: It is simple: you need to call `delete []` for every `new []`.

Comment: OK, I'll update my question a bit... One sec.

Comment: @BЈовић What do you mean?

Comment: in c++, people use smart pointers, and try to avoid raw pointers. In your example, you got double pointer. Big no-no for c++

Comment: What @BЈовић means you're one step away from being a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) :)

Comment: @juanchopanza Lol. Just began with C++ a few days ago, so there's that...

Comment: @BЈовић Could you post a better example then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you need to match every `new` with a `delete` so if, as here, you're juggling a whole array of raw pointers, you will indeed need to delete each in turn.

This can be a serious hassle if the code between `new` and `delete` isn't straightforward, and almost impossible to ensure if it might throw exceptions. For that reason, you should always use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) types such as containers and smart pointers to manage dynamic resources. In this case, `vector<vector<int>>`  might be an appropriate choice.

> I guess the real question is "What does `delete` and `delete[]` really do behind the scene?"

If the object type has a non-trivial destructor, it calls that destructor on each object before deallocating the memory. Thus RAII types will automatically release whatever resource they manage through their destructor; but raw pointers don't have destructors, so deleting them will not free any memory that they point to.

Answer (score 3):

As said, in c++ one rarely has more then one indirection through pointers. In a matter of fact, in c++ pointers are avoided whenever possible.

> In case I need to call delete once for each new statement, is there a way to rewrite my code so that I only need a single delete statement?

One way would be :

```
int *paMatrix = new int[r*c];
```

but then you need to play with indexes.

Another solution (without pointers) without even one delete statement is to use `std::vector` :

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > > paMatrix( r, std::vector< int >( c, 0 ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
for(int i=0; i<r; i++)
    delete[] paMatrix[i];

delete[] paMatrix;
```

There's no way around, except smart pointers etc.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, there *is* a way around: smart pointers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the other answers here, you need to match calls to new with calls to delete.

However if you were willing to change your conception of a 2d array, you can simplify it considerably. For example if it truly a matrix of r x c size you could allocate it as a single array of r*c in size:

```
int* paMatrix = new int[r*c];
```

Then you would be able to delete it in a single step.

The tradeoff would be having to index the array using something like `paArray[x+c*y]` instead of the more natural `paArray[x][y]`.